# Wiring Fresh Air Damper to New Ecobee Thermostat

Tags: wiring, thermostat, ventilation

Ok, here's the deal. I currently have a zoned system with a fresh air "ventilator" (actually just a fresh air damper) and I want to install an ecobee thermostat. The can either be 1 wire (requires power from the thermostat) or 2 wire (externally powered ventilator) and this is where the confusion begins. On my current thermostat I have two wires going to my fresh air damper, yellow on U1 and white on the C terminal, and if you look at the damper wiring you see the two wires coming from the thermostat and no other external power source. I believe the installer chose to jumper the C wire at the thermostat which is confusing me to have a 2 wire setup when in fact I actually have a 1 wire setup which gets power from the thermostat.... am I confused?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post a larger photo of the thermostat wiring?

Comment: Here is a larger picture of the thermostat, you can see the two wires going to the damper. Notice there are 2 wires connected to the "C" terminal.

Comment: So where did you put the U1 wire on your ecobee? Can you post a picture of the final product? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

### Your damper *is* a 1 wire setup

Basically, your damper is set up as a "1 wire" setup, as that nomenclature assumes that the C wire is returning directly to the air handler transformer, whereas in your configuration, the C wire is returning back to the thermostat first, and then going from there to the air handler transformer.  So, simply proceed using the "1 wire" instructions, making sure that both C wires land on the C terminal of the Ecobee.

Comment: That's what I thought but wasn't sure, I appreciate your quick response and explanation.

Comment: @JimR -- we thank people around here by upvoting and/or accepting their answers :)